# Pros and Cons of using mount bind versus volumes when running docker images

Tags: docker

So far when I run docker images I usually did:

```
docker run -d -it --name test \
-v $(pwd)/target:/app/
theimage
```

However I am now checking another person docker code and I find something like

```
   docker run -d -it --name test \
    --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/target.target=/app \
    theimage
```

I read that the basic functioning of both are similar.
I would like to hear from experienced Docker users, about what could be the differences and why should I prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

They are identical, except that the `--mount` option is only in newer versions of Docker and has much more verbose syntax.  In principle [`--mount`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#add-bind-mounts-volumes-or-memory-filesystems) supports more options, so you can specify settings like labels for an automatically created named volume, but I've never particularly needed these.

I generally use the `-v` option (or the [short form of Compose `volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3)).  It's a little more convenient and I never need the extra options.  That's doubly true for a simple bind mount like you show.

Comment: (I do not recommend overwriting your entire `/app` directory with a bind mount, though.  This means you're never running the code that's built into your image until you go to deploy it, which is a recipe for failing in production.  You can use a local interpreter to develop and Docker to deploy; there's nothing wrong with that.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sorry but I cannot understand the comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: A Docker image should usually be self-contained: if you go to deploy an image, it contains all of the application code and its dependencies, and you don't separately copy the application code (again) to the target system.  But a bind mount over all of `/app` tends to hide absolutely everything a Dockerfile does, so the container you're running in development has no relation to what you might eventually run in production.  That negates one of the major goals of using Docker, plus it brings a rather inconvenient development environment with it.